# Easier way to limit rows in SELECT subquery?

Tags: sql, oracle

I perform queries on an Oracle database. Let's say I have a table, PEOPLE. Each person can have multiple reference numbers. The reference numbers are stored in a different table, REFERENCENUMBERS.

REFERENCENUMBERS contains a column, PERSON_ID, which is identical to the ID column of the PEOPLE table. It is through this ID that the tables are joined.

Let's say I want to perform a query on the PEOPLE table. However I only want a single reference number returned per person record: i.e if a person has multiple reference numbers, I don't want multiple rows returned per person per reference number.

I choose a criterion for how to select only one reference number: the one which was created earliest. The date of reference number creation is stored in the REFERENCENUMBERS table as DATECREATED.

The following code does this job:

```
SELECT
    PEOPLE.ID,
    PEOPLE.NAME,
    PEOPLE.AGE,
    PEOPLE.ADDRESS,
    -- Subquery to return the earliest-created reference number for this person
    (
    SELECT
        REFERENCENUMBERS.NUMBER 
    FROM
        REFERENCENUMBERS
    WHERE
        REFERENCENUMBERS.PERSON_ID = PEOPLE.ID -- Link back to the main people ID
        AND REFERENCENUMBERS.DATECREATED = 
        -- Sub-sub query simply to match the earliest date
        (
        SELECT
            MIN(R.DATECREATED) -- To ensure that only the earliest-created reference number is returned.
        FROM
            REFERENCENUMBERS R -- Give this sub-sub query an alias for the table
        WHERE
            R.PERSON_ID = PEOPLE.ID -- Link back to the main people ID
        )
    )
FROM
    PEOPLE
WHERE
    PEOPLE.AGE > 18 -- Or whatever
```

However, my question to you knowledgeable SQL people, is.. is there an easier way of doing this? It just appears cumbersome to have to include a sub-sub-query solely for the purpose of finding the earliest date, and limiting the WHERE clause of the sub-query.

There must be an easier, or cleaner way of doing this. Any suggestions?

(By the way - the sample code is greatly simplified from what I'm actually working on. Please don't provide answers which substantively modify my primary query with different-style JOINs etc - thanks).

Comment: any reasons why joins are a nogo?

Comment: 3 reasons: firstly, the base code is generated by the Business Objects application, which uses the above format to join, and after editing I don't want to confuse things. Secondly, as I said, the code is vastly simplified from what I'm actually working on - which involves up to 10 different tables, all linked in various ways. Thirdly, I am not an SQL expert and not au-fait with anything more than a very basic single join.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest would be a top-n filter:

```
select people.id
     , people.name
     , people.age
     , people.address
     , ( select referencenumbers.number
         from   referencenumbers
         where  referencenumbers.person_id = people.id
         order by referencenumbers.datecreated
         fetch first row only )
from   people
where  people.age > 18;
```

[More details here](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/row-limiting-clause-for-top-n-queries-12cr1) (requires Oracle 12.1 or later.)

Or this (works in earlier versions):

```
select people.id
     , people.name
     , people.age
     , people.address
     , ( select min(rn.person_id) keep (dense_rank first order by rn.datecreated)
         from   referencenumbers rn
         where  rn.person_id = people.id )
from   people
where  people.age > 18;
```

(I gave `referencenumbers` a shorter alias for readability.)

Comment: Thanks. I will try this - although I'm unfamiliar with KEEP and DENSE_RANK. I hope it will work in my Oracle. (Thanks for the FROM edit!)

Comment: Oops, added missing line. Thanks

Comment: I'm pleased to say that the second "earlier versions" example works! Thanks again. I will now have to read up about KEEP, DENSE_RANK and FIRST. From what I understand, when you use these, it doesn't actually matter whether you use MIN or MAX (as used above) - right? Or wrong...

Comment: @ChrisMelville that is right, it's only a tiebreaker in case there is more than one person_id for the same datecreated.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT
    PEOPLE.ID,
    PEOPLE.NAME,
    PEOPLE.AGE,
    PEOPLE.ADDRESS,
    REFERENCENUMBERS.NUMBER 
FROM PEOPLE
JOIN REFERENCENUMBERS ON REFERENCENUMBERS.PERSON_ID = PEOPLE.ID -- Link back to the main people ID
JOIN
(
    SELECT
        R.PERSON_ID, 
        MIN(R.DATECREATED) minc -- To ensure that only the earliest-created reference number is returned.
    FROM
        REFERENCENUMBERS R -- Give this sub-sub query an alias for the table
    GROUP BY R.PERSON_ID
) t ON t.minc = REFERENCENUMBERS.DATECREATED and
       t.PERSON_ID = REFERENCENUMBERS.PERSON_ID
WHERE
    PEOPLE.AGE > 18 -- Or whatever
```

Comment: Where does "minc" come from? Is it an alias? How is it defined? Your first use follows the MIN() calculation: is this just used as an alias for that calculation? My version of Oracle uses the word "AS" for this (eg SELECT PEOPLE.ID AS PERSONID). Or are you doing something else?

Comment: i believe both syntaxes work, but yeah, its an alias

Comment: Okay, thanks guys - I will try and see if I can work this into my code with those joins (and work out what it means :)). I'll let you know, thanks.

Comment: Both "MIN(R.DATECREATED) minc" and "MIN(R.DATECREATED) AS minc" will work, as Ralph mentioned. it comes down to coding standards and personal preferences. Some people (including myself) prefer to specify AS to make it clear it's an alias. Others don't see the need as it's an optional parameter.

Comment: Thanks again - I have voted this up as I'm sure it would work as described, however with these complicated (for me) joins, I have been unable to work them into the code I am actually using (as there are just too many tables with complex relationships). Possibly a seasoned SQL expert would be able to do so, but it's beyond my understanding to apply this to what I'm actually working with. But thanks again.